# Building .Net for Mac project - attempt to upload gets "UIKit could not be found"

Tags: macos, .net-core

I've upgraded a Xamarin.Mac application to .Net 7 and .Net for Mac.
It used to upload to the Mac App Store with no problems.
My first attempt to upload after the upgrade gets the following errors... So what on earth in a MAC app is requesting UIKit???

[image]

There is a lot of business logic and some GUI code that is shared between the Mac and iOS versions of the application. However I have confirmed - the source is all guarded with `#if __IOS__` and there are no iOS libraries being included in the Mac app.

I've searched the Release/.app folder for instances of the string UIKit, and the only place I can find those is in the Microsoft.macOS.dll file.

```
% grep -i UIKit * */* */*/* */*/*/* 2> /dev/null  
Binary file Contents/MonoBundle/Microsoft.macOS.dll matches
```

*(yes... I could have used find | xargs...). :-)*

What is going on here? That dll is required - it cannot be removed and is included in all mac .net apps by default. Does it really pull in UIKit?

Further... it appears that .net 7 on VSMac 17.5.6 (latest) doesn't allow me to set the linker options (in case linking was the problem).

Note that I can build and run both the debug and release versions on my mac, and they run fine.

Any ideas on what is going on?
Many thanks.
Paul.

Comment: It appears that LinkMode is no longer visible in the project options for .Net for Mac projects. So I manually changed the LinkMode from None to SdkOnly and Full - neither of which worked. What on earth is referencing UIKit/UIView etc in a Mac app?